# Composer Update Not working

Tags: composer

I have googled everywhere to find an answer to my issues.

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>    Your configuration does not allow connections to http://packages.firegento.com/packages.json. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
>   [image]

I can't find firegento in my composer.json in the .git repository anywhere.  This also seems to be only with my particular computer in our projects.  I am using OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to check your config.json for composer.

Typically located at ~/.composer/config.json might looking something like this:

`{
    "config": {},
    "repositories": {
        "firegento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packages.firegento.com"
        }
    }
}`

Change `"url": "http://packages.firegento.com"` to `"url": "https://packages.firegento.com"`

Should look like:

`{
    "config": {},
    "repositories": {
        "firegento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.firegento.com"
        }
    }
}`